# How can I call random jpg from sd card and display using drawSdJpeg

Tags: arduino

In the TFT_ESPI (Bodmer) Example/Generic/ESP32_SDcard_jpeg

I have run it on my esp32 on a 3.5" ili9341 with no problems.
I have changed the sd file names to numbers and called them as such ...
`drawSdJpeg("/1.jpg", 0, 0);`     and as expected, runs the same.

I have used this code to display the images one after another   ...

```
`File file;
File root = SD.open("/");
if(!root){
Serial.println("Failed to open root directory");
return;
}
file = root.openNextFile(); // Opens next file in root
while(file)
{
if(!file.isDirectory())
{
drawSdJpeg(file.name(), 0, 0); // This draws a jpeg pulled off the SD Card
delay(4000);
}
file = root.openNextFile(); // Opens next file in root
}
root.close();`
```

But I can't find a way to call a RANDOM file (image) and display it.

Can anyone help please, I would appreciate it.
Thank you.

And thank you to Bodmer for making many things possible !

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
**Thanks to Bodmer**

Yes, the drawSdJpeg function expects a string, so you need to create a string with the number in it plus the .jpg extension. For example:

```
char filename [20]; // 19 chars max + terminating null
int i = 42;
itoa(i,filename,10); // Put string version of a number in filename, 
number base 10
strcat(filename, ".jpg"); // add .jpg to end of string
drawSdJpeg(filename, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Who is Bodmar? Where did they suggest this? Did they delete a comment or answer? Or perhaps your answer should include a link to another URL where you found the solution?